# Plotting histogram for each feature based on target label

Tags: python, matplotlib, data-visualization, histogram

I am trying to plot histograms for each feature and seperate the categories into 0 and 1 which are target values. I have total of 9 features.
I would like to have output similar to
[this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ct6c4.png)

```py
X=merged.iloc[:,0:10]
io=merged['target'][merged['target']==0]
nio=merged['target'][merged['target']==1]
fig,axes =plt.subplots(3,3, figsize=(12, 9))
ax=axes.ravel()

for i,column in enumerate(X.columns):
  _,bins=np.histogram(X[column],bins=40)
  ax[i].hist(io[column],bins=bins,color='r',alpha=.5)
  ax[i].hist(nio[column],bins=bins,color='g',alpha=0.3) 
  ax[i].axes.get_xaxis().set_visible(False)
  ax[i].set_yticks(())
ax[0].legend(['Negative','Positive'],loc='best',fontsize=8)
plt.tight_layout()
plt.show()
```

So far, I have tried this. But I'm getting a key error.

Comment: `X=merged.iloc[:,0:10]` seems to indicate that you have 10 columns (0, 1, 2, ..., 9). Maybe try `X=merged.iloc[:,0:9]`? Or `X=merged.iloc[:,1:10]`?